# Why does an automated build keep failing for solution hosted on Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration

I configured a build policy that builds every successful check in to Visual Studio Online, but I keep getting this error:

```
Summary
    Other Errors
1 error(s)
    Exception Message: The path '$/myproject/mysulution.sln' could not be converted to a local path. Make sure this path is relative to the 'src' folder on the build machine or specify a full server path.
(type ArgumentException)
    Exception Stack Trace: 
    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core.LocalPathProvider.GetLocalPath(String incomingPath)
    at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance,     ActivityExecutor executor, 
BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
    at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

I am using the hosted build controller and my build folder is on my local PC.

Answer (score 30):

I just had the same error. Check if the server path in the "Source Settings" tab of your build definition is the same as the path in your "Process" by Projects to build. The mine was different. I accidentally selected the wrong branch...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the path from '$/myproject/mysulution.sln' to 'mysulution.sln' in your Build configuration

Comment: is like the $/ is required. see the error message:TF10125.The path 'mysolution.sln'must start with $/

Comment: ,No. i mean is not working. the $ Sign is required,when i remove it i got another error message:TF10125.The path 'mysolution.sln'must start with $/

Comment: What option have you selected in the Build Defaults -> Staging location: ?

Comment: i use the 2nd option:Copy build output to the following drop folder(UNC path,such as \\server\share.

Comment: and i want the sharefolder to be on my visualstudio team project

Comment: Ok, I believe you need to setup permissions on the shared folders. Not entirely sure, you have to look into the security settings and change accordingly.

Comment: Just to see if the build work, try the third option "Copy build output to the server" and my previously suggestion solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a 'feature' of the new TFS 2013 build server.
I have customised the TFS2013 default build template to use the old workspace creation and I can't get the solution to build if i provide a full server path in projects to build.

However if I do the same thing with the vanilla default template it works...

It is very frustrating and annoying that microsoft have changed the way you need to define solutions to build.

For reference I keep getting this error also.

```
Exception Message: The path '$/ALM/src/Release/TestClass1/TestClass1/TestClass1.sln' could not be converted to a local path. Make sure this path is relative to the 'src' folder on the build machine or specify a full server path. (type ArgumentException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Core.LocalPathProvider.GetLocalPath(String incomingPath)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```